# Where is npm run looking for the scripts?

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine

When I type `npm run test` in the command line, npm goes to `package.json`, to the `"scripts"` section and tries to match `"test"` there.

The line behind "test" is the following:

```json
"JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=./spec/support/jasmine.json jasmine-run"
```

but the first part (everything except `jasmine-run`) can be removed witout problems (I have a similarily structured project where it works, so I can test these modifications).

Where is npm looking for `jasmine-run`?

Because since I have a project where the script provided works, I could look for it, but the answer is: in the `node_modules` folder next to `package.json` is a module, in whose `package.json` has, in the `"bin"` section:

```json
"jasmine-run": "tools/jasmine-run/jasmine-run.js",
```

However, this exact setup exists in both projects and in one everything works, while in the other `jasmine-run` cannot be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run a script with npm like :

```
npm run-script <name>
```

or with a shortcut like

```
npm test or npm start,
```

your current package directory's bin directory is placed at the front of your path. 
For your and in many of the cases will probably be 
`./node_modules/.bin/`, 
which contains a link to your package's executable scripts.

Anyway you have all the explanation how npm runs work here : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Comment: the .bin folder was the solution, somehow our install script forgot to make a link in the new project, thanks!!!

Comment: yes and sometimes there is a problem as well if you have to versions of a module installed in your system. For example if you have imagine moca module global and local and the versions are different you could have trouble as well! Anyway glad it helps!

Answer (score 2):

npm run adds node_modules/.bin to the PATH provided to scripts. Any binaries provided by locally-installed dependencies can be used without the node_modules/.bin prefix.

Check if you can locate jasmine-run inside node_modules/.bin directory.

For reference have a look at this post: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else ends up here looking for the answer after running create-react-app, here is where I found them.

The line from `package.json` is

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

In VSCode, open the `node_modules` and scroll down to `react-scripts`.
Then open up 'scripts', and there they are.