# Why does "npm start" work but not "react-scripts start" which is what "npm start" apparently executes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

In my `package.json` I have the following scripts block:

```
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
```

I understand that when we type `npm start` or `npm run start` it executes the command listed in the scripts block under `start`.

When I type `npm start` it starts my React app.

Why is it then when I type `react-scripts start`, that it says:

```
bash: react-scripts: command not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is npm run looking for the scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272015/where-is-npm-run-looking-for-the-scripts)

Comment: `npm install -g react-scripts` will get you the lib gobally accessible to run it directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you globally installed `react-scripts` you can run it.

```bash
npm install -g react-scripts
```

But in your setup, it is under node modules. So, only npm can run it.

```
./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. When I execute `./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start` then it starts the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont prefer to install `react-scripts` globally, you can go to the project / repository directory containing `.node_modules` and then run:

```
node ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start
```